# wicket modal popup close issue

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-1.5

I have a page from where i called a modal pop up. Again on save action I called another confirm modal popup. Now when I click on ok then I am supposed to close both modal pop up. Its working fine in all broswer except IE9 AND Chrome.

Error:

```
Wicket.Ajax: Wicket.Ajax.Call.failure: Error while parsing response: 
Could not find root <ajax-response> element wicket-ajax-debug-ver-1356005121064.js:91
WicketAjaxDebug.logError wicket-ajax-debug-ver-1356005121064.js:91
Wicket.Log.error wicket-ajax-ver-1356005121064.js:116
Wicket.Ajax.Call.failure wicket-ajax-ver-1356005121064.js:1098
Wicket.Ajax.Call.loadedCallback wicket-ajax-ver-1356005121064.js:1297
Wicket.Ajax.Request.stateChangeCallback wicket-ajax-ver-1356005121064.js:1048
Wicket.Window.close modal-ver-1356005121079.js:822
close`enter code here`
```

Comment: One more update if i use chrome in debug mode for js file of wicket then no error appears . to me it seems some time delay issue . can someone please help. Thanks

Comment: can you add your code here?

Comment: code i can't add :( . but on debug of IE 9 js i found below message causing the issue.[+]  message "Unable to get value of the property \'getElementsByTagName\': object is null or undefined" String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue. Just thought anyone else may use this way to solve, so sharing my thoughts. Here I have closed the top modal pop up first and then closedcallback of top modal popup I have closed the second modal popup.